# No me funciona el evento prevent default

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

tengo el siguiente problema:

Estoy intentando eliminar la accion por default de cuando das click en un enlace que tiene como ancla un id (para crear un jumplink) no me cancela dicho evento, estoy trabajando en worpress editando la plantilla, si alguien sabe porque es y como podria solucionarlo estaria muy agradecido.
Un saludo, paso captura del codigo[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: además de eso, añade: `e.stopPropagation();`

Comment: El código debe ir como texto, por favor. ;)

Comment: Hola te invito a hacer el [tour] y ver [ask] para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida en la comunidad.